# SharePoint OWACalendarPart : "An error occurred while attempting to add the item to the page."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar, web-part-gallery

I'm trying to use Outlook Web Access Web part in SharePoint Server 2013.
I have added the OWACalendarPart web part to Web part Gallery using following Methods.

```
1) Go to Web part Gallery.

2) On Web part Gallery page, Click Files-> New Document -> New in the ribbon.

3) On New web part page, look for Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWACalendarPart, 
   Select the web part and click on populate gallery.
```

Now, I navigate to the SharePoint page where i want to add web part, clicked on Add web part. UnderMiscellaneous Category, I see OWACalendarPart.

When I click add, the page always saying "**An error occurred while attempting to add the item to the page**."

I tried Several Times But Nothing helped.How to add this OWACalendarPart to the page?

UPDATE :

This is the error I get from Log.

```
An error occurred while attempting to add the gallery item [Miscellaneous]     OWACalendarPart to the page. 
The error was: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWAPartBase.get_OWAServerAddressRoot()    
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterOWACalendarPart.Write13_OWACalendarPart(String n, String ns, OWACalendarPart o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)     
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterOWACalendarPart.Write14_WebPart(Object o)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)    
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.WriteXmlAsBytes(XmlSerializer xmls)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags, SPSerializationBinderBase serializationBinder, BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags, SPSerializationBinderBase serializationBinder)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartToStore(WebPart webPart, Int32 viewId, String viewGuid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartGallerySourceBase.AddItemToPage(WebPartZoneBase zone, Int32 zoneIndex, WebPart webPart)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartGallerySourceBase.AddItemToPage(WebPartZoneBase zone, Int32 zoneIndex, WebPartGalleryItem item, String wpid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartAdder.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this On-premise Sharepoint instance? If so then you should look up Correlation ID and search in Logs to find more. If this is Sharepoint Online (Office 365 tenant) Exchange Online as mail server is not supporter.

Alternative is to use Page Viewer

- http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2012/05/29/outlook-web-app-in-sharepoint-online.aspx
- Sharepoint Logs http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463595(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: This is On-premise Sharepoint instance.It gives error without Correlation ID.It displays only the  pop up message saying "An error occurred while attempting to add the item to the page.""

Comment: I would go in ULS Viewer, reproduce the steps to get the same error and stoped capturing Logs .. Review all the log entries to that point ..

Comment: I've updated the error log above.